# C# Prevent update record to another record exist in database

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a record in database as below

```
 ID     Code    Description
 1       A       test1
 2       B       test2
 3       C       test3
```

If user click to update record 3 and change the code C to code A then click update, I want show a message to user the record exist.  If user change the description only and update, it's allow.

How I can validate it .  This is a winforms apps.

Comment: try remote validation https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/remote-validation-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: you can use AJAX to check updated code existed or not

Comment: Why not just place a unique key on Code? The database will then reject any attempt to create or edit another record to have the same Code.

Comment: If I put unique key on column code, when user updating record 3 but just change the description, it will still return error?  Beside place a unique in Code column in table, any other way can do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to check that A exists you can put a unique key on the code-column so you will retrieve an error if you try to update the record to a still existing value.

Comment: If I put unique key on column code, when user updating record 3 but just change the description, it will still return error?

Comment: if you manualy update the database you could analyze the error and update the row witthout colum `code`.

Comment: Why would it return an error if you update the description column? I am assuming `unique key constraint` on code column. Just put the code column in `WHERE` clause